# How Calculate change rate over time with tabular dataset in google data studio?

Tags: time-series, looker-studio

I seek your valuable support in finding a way to calculate change rate over time with tabular dataset in google data studio. Here is the link to the dataset: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1To1n5JJA6uVkLMgwjKhghJgCJpFmtXkqNog4DzfoEbE/edit?usp=sharing

There are many rows with data stamp and have different categories and sub categories. I have created a change rate table manually based on which I want to create charts in google data studio. The charts will be from the raw tabular data not the separate change rate table that is built only for example purpose.

So the chart could be based on a main category (as in the sample) and can also be viewed as sub-category and show change rate over time between the dates.

The dates can sometimes be months or years. I am not very savy with advanced formulas or scripting but I am hopeful someone here would be able to help me out on this. I will be ever so grateful for this :)

Answer (score 0):

I can only provide you with the quotient of datasets between two days. If you need different mappings between dates (day, months, years), for each the following steps have to be done:

- generate a new field "yesterday" with: DATETIME_SUB(date, INTERVAL 1 day)
- blend this dataset with itself, using as dimension "date" and "yesterday".
- Further dimensions are your categories fields A and B.
- As metric, you can use the count of the date field.